# I tried in command prompt this but it failed

Tags: restore, session

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\War Machine>C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Rocketmelt\Application\Rocketmelt.exe --restore-last-session
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Users\War Machine>
```

Comment: what is your issue? what do you want to do? You miss your username after C:\Users\. try **C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Rocketmelt\Application\Rocketmelt.exe** if your account name is John.

Comment: My username is War Machine lol

Comment: try this: **%LOCALAPPDATA%\Rocketmelt\Application\Rocketmelt.exe  --restore-last-session**

Comment: C:\Users\War Machine>%LOCALAPPDATA%\Rocketmelt\Application\Rocketmelt.exe --rest
ore-last-session -
'C:\Users\War' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\War Machine>

Comment: C:\Users\War Machine>C:\Users\War Machine>%LOCALAPPDATA%\Rocketmelt\Application\
Rocketmelt.exe --rest
Access is denied.

Comment: grrr it keeps saying access is denied and I am on administrator for my computer FYI

Comment: I have tried everything with my rocketmelt browser to either restore previous session or the history or the tabs it all fails badly

Comment: run the **cmd.exe** as admin: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/How-do-I-run-an-application-once-with-a-full-administrator-access-token

Comment: C:\Windows\system32>%LOCALAPPDATA%\Rocketmelt\Application\ Rocketmelt.exe --rest

'C:\Users\War' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: this time I never put user war and yet it says something about it lol

Comment: I think all my online work is lost forever unless there is some way of digging up the history which was wiped when the computer did a forced update

Comment: install this addon: http://code.kliu.org/cmdopen/, go to the folder where the exe is stored, make a rightclick and open the elevated command prompt. Now run the command.

Answer (score 2):

Because your username includes a space, you must put quotes around the command.

```
"C:\Users\War Machine\AppData\Local\Rocketmelt\Application\Rocketmelt.exe" --restore-last-session
```

Without the space, it's interpreted as:

```
Command   ->  C:\Users\War
Argument1 ->  Machine\AppData\Local\Rocketmelt\Application\Rocketmelt.exe
Argument2 ->  --restore-last-session
```

Comment: ok I did it and now -> The system cannot find the path specified. <- now this comes up when the quotes in place...

Comment: @JohnPasssecret: Where *is* Rocketmelt.exe then? Just `cd "C:\path\to\dir with Rocketmelt.exe"` first, then run `Rocketmelt.exe --restore-last-session` in that directory.